# Django rest framework gis-leaflet plotting and cordinates

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, leaflet, gis

I am using django restframework gis and using geofeaturemodel serializer to generate geojson response.But the co-ordinates i am getting seems to wrong in some other projection system(assuming projected coordinate system).Can we convert that coordinate system into geometric coordinate system in the rest framework gis so that in the frontend it can be plotted using leaflet library

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
  "type": "MultiPoint",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      2048157.72954293,
      765203.671727644
    ]
  ]
},
"bbox": [
  2048157.72954293,
  765203.671727644,
  2048157.72954293,
  765203.671727644
],
"properties": {
  "autogenera": 40,
  "name": "111A-CB",
  "networknam": "PROP STORM POND EAST",
  "rimelevati": 367.464470905157,
  "partsizena": "48 x 48 Rect Structure 24 x 36 Frm"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define the CRS in your source data? Is it the same as the output?

1)If you have a different output crs expectation, you can do the reprojection or define in the data source. 
2)You can always extract geometry from geojson and plot it. But leaflet can use geojson as input for rendering, not sure why you have to do that conversion though.